# std::variant cout in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variant

I am relatively new to CPP and have recently stumbled upon `std::variant` for C++17.

However, I am unable to use the `<<` operator on such type of data.

Considering

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    variant<int, string> a = "Hello";
    cout<<a;
}
```

I am unable to print the output. Is there any *short* way of doing this? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `std::get`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    variant<int, string> a = "Hello";
    cout << std::get<string>(a);
}
```

If you want to get automatically, it can't be done without knowing its type. Maybe you can try this.

```
string s = "Hello";
variant<int, string> a = s;

cout << std::get<decltype(s)>(a);
```

Comment: Ohhh, thx a lot. Is there by any chance any means of doing this automatically?. Like if `a` changes value along the program to become `4` instead of `"Hello"`?

Comment: @edvilme No, there isn't any standard of getting value automatically.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. Well thanks a lot anyways. :D

Comment: @edvilme check  @bill-lynch's reply at the bottom, using `std::visit` will work with any type that for which an overload of the `operator<<` is found

Answer (score 16):

You can use `std::visit` if you don't want to use `std::get`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct make_string_functor {
  std::string operator()(const std::string &x) const { return x; }
  std::string operator()(int x) const { return std::to_string(x); }
};

int main() {
  const std::variant<int, std::string> v = "hello";

  // option 1
  std::cout << std::visit(make_string_functor(), v) << "\n";

  // option 2  
  std::visit([](const auto &x) { std::cout << x; }, v);
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int main( )
{

    std::variant<int, std::string> variant = "Hello";

    std::string string_1 = std::get<std::string>( variant ); // get value by type
    std::string string_2 = std::get<1>( variant ); // get value by index
    std::cout << string_1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << string_2 << std::endl;
    //may throw exception if index is specified wrong or type
    //Throws std::bad_variant_access on errors

    //there is also one way to take value std::visit
}
```

Here is the description link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant